# Driver for my fingerprint reader are not found or configured up to linux kernel version 5.8 so how to resolve this issue?

Tags: drivers, kernel, 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad

I have a lenovo thinkpad E14 which has a finger print reader of 'Goodix FingerPrint Device' and drivers for the above mentioned device are not found till linux kernel 5.8. So how to find drivers for it and if drivers are not made of this device then how to request the community for drivers. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 .

Comment: If there is no driver, there is no way to find it. You can either write a driver yourself, or wait for someone else does it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu *groovy* in development is using the 5.8 kernel

Ubuntu 20.04 with HWE enabled will upgrade to using the 20.10 stack with Ubuntu 20.04.2 (ie. the 5.8 kernel). That's a *distance* away currently, as whilst the release of Ubuntu 20.10 (now *groovy*) is known the release date for 20.04.2 has currently not been scheduled

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule for the schedule

I don't see any point in making a request for it as its already planned; it'll occur when 20.04.2 is out; alas that date is unknown at this stage (*late this year maybe, if not early 2021*).

*Focal* dailies are available if you'd like to try it, but whilst the 5.8 kernel maybe there already, I'm unsure sorry as I've not run one since *groovy* was bumped to 5.8 - http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/

Comment: It seems that there is no driver in 5.8 either.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have a doubt if i upgrade to ubuntu 20.10 can i find driver for finger print scanner now.

Comment: I saw talk today of later 5.8 kernels being built for *test* (*dev* channels on IRC), maybe it'll be in them (we're not at kernel freeze yet, alas it is getting close) @Pilot6   I don't pay much attention to that detail as doesn't impact what I do...

Comment: It is quite easy to check by installing a mainline kernel now. If the scanner really works in some kernel, the question will make sense.

Comment: Kernel modules (drivers) are built for specific kernels, the daily images allow you to run tests on what is currently available (or really what will become the released versions) which is why I used that link.  If you want to go upstream you can too, but i'd avoid it for security reasons (you take on the updating & upgrading yourself having replaced the Ubuntu packaging; if you do it correctly you're okay, make a mistake.. which continues into the future.. ie. your responsibility when kernels reach EOL to bump yourself manually)